# Code breaking: Find the Message

Tags: cipher, encoded-message

Just a short but really scary looking code breaking challenge.

It breaks down into a couple of sentences once cracked.

24141325121914011720242320110720150920201224161720111012190613080310160806252412191417050526212017171013

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First step:

> Split the digits into pairs:
>  Result is `24, 14, 13, 25, 12, 19, 14, 01, 17, 20, 24, 23, 20, 11, 07, 20, 15, 09, 20, 20, 12, 24, 16, 17, 20, 11, 10, 12, 19, 06, 13, 08, 03, 10, 16, 08, 06, 25, 24, 12, 19, 14, 17, 05, 05, 26, 21, 20, 17, 17, 10, 13`.

Second step:

> Convert `01` to `a`, `02` to `b`, `03` to `c`, ... `26` to `z`
>  Result is **`xnmylsnaqtxwtkgtoittlxpqtkjlsfmhcjphfyxlsnqeezutqqjm`**.

Third step:

> Rotate 5 letters in the backward direction (or equivalently 21 in the forward direction).
>  This changes `f` to `a`, `g` to `b`, `h` to `c`, `i` to `d`, ..., `y` to `t`, `z` to `u`, `a` to `v`, `b` to `w`, `c` to `x`, `d` to `y` and `e` to `z`.
>  Result is **`sihtgnivlosrofbojdoogsklofegnahcxekcatsgnilzzupolleh`**.

Fourth step:

> Reverse the string.
>  Result is **`hellopuzzlingstackexchangefolksgoodjobforsolvingthis`**.

Fifth (and final) step:

> Add some spaces.
>  Result is **`hello puzzling stack exchange folks good job for solving this`**, which is the plain-text message.

A note about the message:

> The original message had two typos in the plain-text message. Originally it was
>  "24141325121914011720242320 **16** 0720150920201224161720111012190613080310160806252412191417050526 **22** 2017171013",
>  instead of
>  "24141325121914011720242320 **11** 0720150920201224161720111012190613080310160806252412191417050526 **21** 2017171013"
>  which used to produce the plain-text message **`hello quzzling stack exchange folks good job kor solving this`**, but the OP already fixed that.

Comment: Step 6. Type correct "hello quzzling stack exchange folks good job kor solving this" -> "hello puzzling stack exchange folks good job for solving this"

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the errors. I have fixed the errors in the post.

Comment: @ColorfullyMonochrome Ok, I have changed the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

Splitting the digits into groups of two and taking letters

`241413... = 24,14,13,... = XNM...`

gives the length-52 string

`'XNMYLSNAQTXWTPGTOITTLXPQTKJLSFMHCJPHFYXLSNQEEZVTQQJM'`

This method is implicitly confirmed in that all the resulting indices are 1 through 26, which is unlikely in a random string of numbers.

I don't care to go further though because now it's just a random-looking string of letters, too short to do any meaningful cryptanalysis, and I see nothing better to do then throw methods at it until one works. I did try Caesar cipher though; none of the shifts produced anything meaningful.

Comment: Actually, caesar shift was correct (ROT5) - then the result is backwards.

Comment: +1 for reasoning the 'split' is correct even without finding a clear text.